# Adjoint of Matrix in C++. (Inverse of Matrix)

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, c++17, matrix-inverse

I am Implementing a Inverse Matrix by using the following formula

```
Inverse of A = (Adj of A) / (Determinant of A)
```

I am implementing Adjoint Matrix, But When I printing the result of `adjoint` function , the result is printed in this way.

```
-23 -20 34
19 4 -14
-8 4 4
```

But it should be In the following order

```
-23 19 -8
-20 4 4 
34 -14 4
```

Here, rows became the column. But when I debug the code I found this

```
[0]:{...}
  [0] -23
  [1] 19
  [2] -8
[1]:{...}
  [0] -20
  [1]  4
  [2]  4
[2]:{...}
  [0] 34
  [1] -14
  [2] -4
```

According to debugger result, is the result is correct???
I am not getting why the result is printing in that way.
Here Is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> 

/* Function call for to get Cofactor of Matrix */
void getCofactor(std:: vector< std :: vector <int >> &vec, std:: vector< std :: vector <int >> &temp, int p, int q){
    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp(3, std::vector<int>(3));
    int i =0;
    int j = 0;
    for(int row =0; row< vec.size(); row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < vec.size(); col++)
        {
            //copying into temporary matix only those element which are not given row and column
            if(row != p && col != q){
                
                temp[i][j++] = vec[row][col];
            }

            if (j == vec.size() - 1) {
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
            }
        }

    }

}

int determinent (std:: vector< std :: vector <int >> &vec, int n){
    int D = 0; // Initializa the result 
    // Base case: if the matrix contains single element
    if(n==1){
        return vec[0][0];
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp(3, std::vector<int>(3));
    int sign = 1;
    for(int f = 0; f<vec.size(); f++){
        //get cofactor of vec[0][f]
        getCofactor(vec, temp, 0,  f);
        D += sign * vec[0][f] * determinent(temp, n-1);

        //terms are to be added with alternate sign
        sign = -sign;
    }
    return D;
}

/* Function Call for Adjoint Matrix */
void adjoint(std:: vector< std :: vector <int >> &vec, std:: vector< std :: vector <int >> &adj){
    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj(vec.size(), std::vector<int>(vec.size()));
    if (vec.size() == 1){
        adj[0][0] = 1;
        return;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp(vec.size(), std::vector<int>(vec.size()));
    int sign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++){
            //Get Co-factor of the Matrix[i][j]
            getCofactor(vec,temp, i, j);
            //Sign of adj[i][j] positive if sum of row and column indexs is even
            sign = ((i + j) % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
            // Interchanging rows and columns to get the transpose of the cofector Matrix
            adj[j][i] = (sign) * (determinent(temp, vec.size() - 1));
            std:: cout <<adj[j][i]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }  
}

/* Display Function */
void display (std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec){
     for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++) {
            std :: cout<< vec[i][j]<<" ";
        } 
        std:: cout << std::endl;  
    }
}

int main(){
    
    std :: vector < std :: vector< int > > matrix = {{2,1,3},{6,5,7},{4,9,8}}; // Initialize the vector
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Ad(matrix.size(), std::vector<int>(matrix.size()));
    std :: cout << "The Given Matrix is: "<<std :: endl;
    display(matrix);
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The Adjacent Matrix is: "<< std::endl; 
    adjoint(matrix, Ad);
    display(Ad); 
    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve this?
The `display` function is not printing result of `adjoint` function. How can I print the result of `adjoint` function through `display` function

Comment: Your question is about the `adjoint()` and `display()` functions. Please remove the unnecessary fluff (the multiplication and inversion) from your example. Initialize `matrix` to the values it should have when `adjoint()` is called. I'd also recommend something like `using Matrix2D = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;` to make your code easier to read.

Comment: There is output produced by both `display()` and `adjoint()`, yet you presented the output from only one of these. Please provide the full output produced by your program (after removing the unnecessary steps), along with the full expected output. *Sorry, but deciding to ignore some of the output is reserved for those who know what is going wrong. As the person asking, you don't get that latitude. You do, however, have the latitude to remove output from your program, to better focus on the problem. ;)*

Comment: Finally, there are too many undefined symbols for this to be a reproducible example, something that I can copy-paste to an online compiler to reproduce your result. (A [mre] requires a balance between "minimal" -- removing fluff -- and "reproducible".)

Comment: @JaMiT I have edited the post, as you suggested.

Comment: Better, but your output still does not match your code. You have shown three lines of output, but your code produces 12 lines, one of them blank. Among the 12 lines are both the output you reported getting and the output you reported expecting. So... a bit confusing to the reader. In this case, the better course of action might be to remove the lines that produce output except for the lines producing the output you have focused on. That is, make your code produce just those three lines of output.

Comment: should I add, one more loop in the `display` function? for example `for(int k = 0; k<vec.size(); k++) ` and I did not got, what did you mean by 12 lines out put?

Comment: *"what did you mean by 12 lines out put?"* -- I mean that I copied your code into an online compiler, ran it, and got 12 lines of output. You should try this yourself to see what happens. (There is a list of online compilers about 2/3 down the [c++ tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info),) The first line was `The Given Matrix is: `, followed by three lines containing numbers, followed by a blank line, followed by `The Adjacent Matrix is: `, followed by six lines containing numbers. So 1+3+1+1+6 == 12 lines.

Comment: That formula does not produce the inverse of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. if you comment out the debug print calls to std::cout in void `adjoint()`, the unwanted output disappears.

```
void adjoint(std:: vector< std :: vector <int >> &vec, std:: vector< std :: vector <int >> &adj){
    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj(vec.size(), std::vector<int>(vec.size()));
    if (vec.size() == 1){
        adj[0][0] = 1;
        return;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp(vec.size(), std::vector<int>(vec.size()));
    int sign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++){
            //Get Co-factor of the Matrix[i][j]
            getCofactor(vec,temp, i, j);
            //Sign of adj[i][j] positive if sum of row and column indexs is even
            sign = ((i + j) % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
            // Interchanging rows and columns to get the transpose of the cofector Matrix
            adj[j][i] = (sign) * (determinent(temp, vec.size() - 1));

            // Comment this out:
            std:: cout <<adj[j][i]<<" ";
        }
        // Comment this out:
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }  
}
```

That's it.

Execution output:

```
Program returned: 0
Program stdout

The Given Matrix is: 
2 1 3 
6 5 7 
4 9 8 

The Adjacent Matrix is: 
-23 19 -8 
-20 4 4 
34 -14 4
```

You can run and test your corrected code here:

https://godbolt.org/z/PzqKMsrsv

No more comments.